# jQuery throws out a wrong number?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple roulette wheel using jQuery.

I can spin the wheel using the jquery exactly like what I want but for some strange reason the jquery code spits out a wrong number!

here is my code:

JQUERY CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
        window.WHEELOFFORTUNE = {

            cache: {},

            init: function () {
                console.log('controller init...');

                var _this = this;
                this.cache.wheel = $('.wheel');
                this.cache.wheelMarker = $('.marker');
                this.cache.wheelSpinBtn = $('.wheel');

                //mapping is backwards as wheel spins clockwise //1=win
                               this.cache.wheelMapping = [5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26,0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10].reverse();

                this.cache.wheelSpinBtn.on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) _this.spin();
                });

                //reset wheel
                this.resetSpin();

                //setup prize events
                this.prizeEvents();
            },

            spin: function () {
                console.log('spinning wheel');

                var _this = this;

                // reset wheel
                this.resetSpin();

                //disable spin button while in progress
                this.cache.wheelSpinBtn.addClass('disabled');

                /*
                    Wheel has 10 sections.
                    Each section is 360/10 = 36deg.
                */
                var deg = 1500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1500),
                    duration = 20000; //optimal 6 secs

                _this.cache.wheelPos = deg;

                //transition queuing
                //ff bug with easeOutBack
                this.cache.wheel.transition({
                    rotate: '0deg'
                }, 0)
                    .transition({
                    rotate: deg + 'deg'
                }, duration, 'easeOutCubic');

                //move marker
                _this.cache.wheelMarker.transition({
                    rotate: '-37deg'
                }, 0, 'snap');

                //just before wheel finish
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //reset marker
                    _this.cache.wheelMarker.transition({
                        rotate: '0deg'
                    }, 300, 'easeOutQuad');
                }, duration - 500);

                //wheel finish
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // did it win??!?!?!
                    var spin = _this.cache.wheelPos,
                        degrees = spin % 360,
                        percent = (degrees / 360) * 100,
                        segment = Math.ceil((percent / 4)),  //divided by number of segments
                        win = _this.cache.wheelMapping[segment - 1]; //zero based array

                    console.log('spin = ' + spin);
                    console.log('degrees = ' + degrees);
                    console.log('percent = ' + percent);
                    console.log('segment = ' + segment);
                    console.log('win = ' + win);

                    //display dialog with slight delay to realise win or not.
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        alert('you won '+win+'!');
                        //window.open('http://form.jotformz.com/form/41336216871655?','_self',false);
                    }, 1500);

                    //re-enable wheel spin
                    _this.cache.wheelSpinBtn.removeClass('disabled');

                }, duration);

            },

            resetSpin: function () {
                this.cache.wheel.transition({
                    rotate: '0deg'
                }, 0);
                this.cache.wheelPos = 0;
            }

        }

        window.WHEELOFFORTUNE.init();
});//]]>  

</script>
```

HTML PART IS VERY SIMPLE:

```
<div class="wheel-wrap">
    <img class="wheel" src="wheelhalf.png" />
    <img class="marker" src="http://jquery4u.com/images/marker.png" />
</div>
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4zs8a07c/

however, it doesn't work in jsfiddle as you will need to include these two lines (jquery libs) to your HTML header.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gasvehicular.net/fuelgas/ruleta//ruleta_files/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gasvehicular.net/fuelgas/ruleta//ruleta_files/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
```

but that is all I have in my HTML file and it works fine locally (apart from the wrong number issue).

so, copy and paste the code from jsfiddle in a blank HTML file and add the two jquery LINKS posted above in the header of the HTML page and you should see it working properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "a wrong number?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey, when the wheel spins, the number that the wheel stops on is different than the number that is shown in the `alert('you won '+win+'!');`

Comment: And that number is...

Comment: @RobertHarvey, could be any number. its a roulette wheel! so it could be any number from 0 to 36. but for EXAMPLE if the wheel stops on number 4, the alert window pops up and shows you won 32, or 7 or any other number when in fact it should say you you won 4.

Comment: How do you know the wheel stopped on number 4?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, because I have `this.cache.wheelMarker = $('.marker');`  and I also have `<img class="marker" src="http://jquery4u.com/images/marker.png" />`... so basically, what happens is that when the wheels stops, the Marker which is an Arrow will point to a Number on the will and this is the winning Number. but when the alert window pops up, it shows a different number than the winning number! does that make sense?

Comment: I tried putting up a JSFiddle, but `wheelhalf.png` is a relative URL, so I can't make it work.  Can you set up a fiddle and put the link here?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, sure. i will put up a fiddle in minute.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, please view my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the 0 in your wheel mapping, so I added it here:

```
         this.cache.wheelMapping = [5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26,0, 32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10].reverse();
```

The math was a bit off when calculating the segment. This new formula now properly gets the index of the correct wheel mapping:

```
segment = Math.ceil(((percent/100) * 36)),
```

The above code worked for me but on JSFiddle I had to adjust the wheelMapping to get the marker to line up with the winning number on the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/wf49mqaa/1/

adjusted wheelmapping on jsfiddle:

```
this.cache.wheelMapping = [1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26,0, 32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33].reverse();
```

Comment: You are my hero mate. been pulling my hair out with this. Thank you very much... a quick question: the math was still a bit out and I changed the code to this: segment = Math.ceil(((percent/100) * 37) - 1), does this makes sense or that is wrong?

Comment: That's doesn't make much sense I me because the 36 coincides with the number of numbers on the wheel. I think I counted 36. If they're are really 37 then it's correct.   As I think about it more the Math .ceil could give you issues because it would turn 1.1 into 2. I think a math.round would be more true.

Comment: it is 37 numbers including 0. so its 1 to 31 and 0. doing it with -1 made it work perfectly.

Comment: sorry I meant 1 to 36 plus 0.